# How to handle Contacts changes in Android?

Tags: android, contacts, observer-pattern, android-event

I want to listen for Contacts changes. How do I do that?

Comment: When do you need to listen? "Always" or just when your application is running?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.

```
protected class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyContentObserver() {
        super(null);
        text.append("created at + " + new GregorianCalendar().getTime() + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        text.append("Changed\n");
    }
}
```

and also we need to register ContentObserver:

```
    this.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .registerContentObserver(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,
                    new MyContentObserver());
```